# How to check where a python module is installed on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

From this [site](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/mac3/), I installed a Python module called `stdio` and whenever I try to run a program with this module I get the error `ImportError: No module named stdio` I don't know where the module is installed and how to make it work so that I can run the program with this module. How would I run my program with this module?

Comment: Have you checked the first entry in the "Q&A" section at the bottom of the page you linked to?

Comment: You need to make sure that the Python you use to install is also the same Python you use to run your program. You probably installed it using the Python 2 built-in on Macs, then you ran your program with Python 3. Read the docs again on how to make sure you are using `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install stdio` first in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, to see where things installed using `python3 setup.py --user` will end up, you can run

```
python3 -m site
```

and look at the definition of `USER_BASE`.

However, in your case, judging by the error message you are getting, I strongly suspect that you are running `python` when you should be running `python3`.